# VBA Deleting Active Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro that deletes the active sheet without displaying the prompt. Which is what the code below does...This works great until the last sheet. I get the prompt no matter what. I do not want to delete the last sheet and at the same time, I don't want the error '1004' message to come up. Is there a way to change the code above to not delete my last sheet and not display the error message at the same time?

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveSheet.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: On Error Resume Next

Answer (score -3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you don't want to delete the last worksheet, and you want to avoid the error message.

You could try this:

```
Sub deleteallbutlast()

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        If Worksheets.Count > 1 Then
            ActiveSheet.Delete
        Else
            End
        End If
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: This unfortunately still showed the error message on the last active sheet.

Answer (score 1):

***If the idea is*** to delete the `ActiveSheet` and only it, this is something that will work, until there is only 1 sheet in the workbook:

```
Sub DeleteActiveSheet()

    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count = 1 Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If

End Sub
```

***If the idea is*** to delete all worksheets, but the last, then follow this sequence:

- assign a worksheet variable `wksToStay` from the type `Worksheet` and set it to the last worksheet in the workbook;
- loop through all the `Worksheets` in the `Workbook.Worksheets` collection, starting from the last one;
- always perform a check, whether the worksheet to be deleted `wksToDelete` has the same name as the `wksToStay`;
- delete, if the name is not the same;
- it will delete all the worksheets, including the [hidden and the very hidden ones](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.visible);

---

```
Sub DeleteAllButLast()

    Dim wksToStay As Worksheet
    Dim wksToDelete As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long

    Set wksToStay = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)

    For i = Worksheets.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set wksToDelete = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i)
        If wksToDelete.Name <> wksToStay.Name Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            wksToDelete.Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Test the next code, please:

```
Sub deleteExceptTheLastSh()
    If ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.count > 1 Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
         ActiveSheet.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Else
        MsgBox "This is the last sheet and it cannot be deleted!"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What is wrong with my code, **against the question to be asked**? I am addressing to the one voting up without understand the code and context. The message box was a bonus, which could easily removed if not wished...

Answer (score -1):

This happens because you cannot delete the last worksheet in a workbook. Is the macro you have executed with a button? If you do not like the 1004 message, one possible solution may be to create a custom error message:

```
Sub deleteActiveSheet()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

 On Error GoTo Error
    ActiveSheet.Delete

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Exit Sub
Error:
 MsgBox "you cannot delete the last worksheet in the workbook!"
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked! All I had to do what not add anything after the Error: command.